# Combining 2 bat files with enable and disable delayedexpansion

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, aggregation

I have 2 bat files working perfectly for my data. One to copy and move some files. The other to group files based on a pattern in their names. I need to combine both in a file or I need to make them work with running one command.

bat 1:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

    rem set language pre-requisites
    rem purpose can be 'test' or 'deploy'
    SET "purpose=test"
    SET "language=English-Indian"
    SET "lang_code=EnIn"

    rem Since we have only 2 options test or deploy
    if "%purpose%"=="test" (
     SET "folder=%lang_code%P101M2Tsub"
    )
    if "%purpose%"=="deploy" (
     SET "folder=%lang_code%P101M2DFull"
    )

    rem set required paths here. Don't edit unless necessary
    SET Source101="D:\..path..\*.wav"
    SET SourceLive="D:\..path..\M2"
    SET Destination="D:\..path..\M3\*"

    rem copying the data
    xcopy  %SourceLive% %Destination% /e /i /h
    rem copying 101 files into the other 100 folders
    for /d %%a in (%Destination%) do copy %Source101% "%%a"

    rem renaming M3 folders
    cd %Destination%
    for /d %%a in (*) do (
      set "p=%%a"
      set "fp=!p:~0,8!" & set "tp=!p:~10!"
      ren %%a !fp!M3!tp!
    )
```

bat 2:

```
@echo off

rem Prepare environment
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem configure where to start
set "root=some path"

rem For each file under root that match indicated pattern
for /r "%root%" %%f in (*_*_*.wav) do (

    rem Split the file name in tokens using the underscore as delimiter
    for /f "tokens=2 delims=_" %%p in ("%%~nf") do (

        rem Test if the file is in the correct place
        for %%d in ("%%~dpf.") do if /i not "%%~p"=="%%~nd" (

            rem if it is not, move it where it should be
            if not exist "%%~dpf\%%~p"  md "%%~dpf\%%~p"
            move "%%~ff" "%%~dpf\%%~p"
        )
    )
)
```

I need to combine these two bat files into one. As in I need one working bat file. Can someone help?

Comment: @Richard I tried combining both in traditional way. It seems to work through bat 1 and ignore the functionality of bat 2

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
....
the work in batch file 1
....
setlocal disabledelayedexpansion
the work in batch file 2
....
endlocal
endlocal
```

Anyway, the only reason for the disabledelayedexpansion in second batch file is to avoid problems with special characters in file/folder names. First batch file doesn't care of it so, if it work, remove the disabledelayedexpansion from second batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Could be as simple as

```
call batch1
call batch2
```

BUT

perhaps the `cd` before the final `for` in batch1 is changing to a directory that batch2 does not expect.

if so, change the `cd` to a `pushd` and add a `popd` after the current last line of batch1.

OR

since the only part of batch1 that appears to REQUIRE delayedexpansion is the final `FOR` loop, change batch1 to disabledelayedexpansion mode, then add

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

directly before the final `for` loop and

```
endlocal
```

on the next line after the final close-parenthesis.